# Angular-UI-Router modal like pinterest

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm making an app with a gallery that looks a lot like http://pinterest.com. In Pinterest, when you click a pin, it shows the pin page over the top of the gallery you were viewing. The URL changes to the pin url, and does not contain any information about the gallery behind the details. You can click the "X" or on the background to get back to the gallery where you were browsing without reloading.

How can I duplicate this with UI-Router?

Needs:

- display the same details modal over several different galleries
- switch to the same details url in all cases
- if the details url is entered cold (from a bookmark or link), just display an empty gray background behind and disable closing

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [angular-ui-router's FAQ](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-open-a-dialogmodal-at-a-certain-state) :

```
$stateProvider.state("items.add", {
    url: "/add",
    onEnter: function($stateParams, $state, $modal, $resource) {
        $modal.open({
            templateUrl: "items/add",
            resolve: {
              item: function() { new Item(123).get(); }
            },
            controller: ['$scope', 'item', function($scope, item) {
              $scope.dismiss = function() {
                $scope.$dismiss();
              };

              $scope.save = function() {
                item.update().then(function() {
                  $scope.$close(true);
                });
              };
            }]
        }).result.then(function(result) {
            if (result) {
                return $state.transitionTo("items");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

It depends on ui-bootstrap for the modal.

If you prefer using `fancybox` or another lightbox, you can use a similar approach. Use the `onEnter` callback to initialize the lightbox, then transition to the parent-state when it closes. (And you might want to add an onExit callback if you transition away without closing the lightbox.)

Comment: I don't understand the resolve and $scope.save parts. Is there a more simple/basic solution to this?

Comment: @DiodeDan It's example code for a modal used to update items, so it has some elements that might not apply in other cases. The `$scope.save` is for the functionality behind a save button on the modal. The `resolve` is for adding things as local properties to the controller (such as the item involved). They can be left out if they're not necessary.

Comment: Is there a way to transition back to the previous state at the `return $state.transitionTo("items");`. Imagine a button on the header of a website, this button opens a modal box, and this modal box could open at any state in the website. Wouldn't it make sense for the state to transition back to the previous state rather than selecting a specific state that a user should go back to? Following on from this, would it make sense to make the modal's url inherit the previous state's url?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai You'd probably have to use the stateTransitionStart/End events to store the previous state, but that much should be doable. But something I've been missing in angular-ui-router is the ability to open a modal as child-state of a collection of states (so that it inherits the url and doesn't clear the ui-view the lies underneath the modal overlay). There are some ideas floating around on angular-ui-router's github, but I don't think they'll develop it anytime soon.

Comment: @towr That problem is exactly what I've been trying to figure out too! It's similar to the multiple inheritance problem. Can a state be a child of multiple states?